# How to hide particular test from generated testng report?

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

I am using testng for my automation test framework.

Here is the `testng.xml`:

```xml
<test name="Suite Run (Please ignore this)">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.aaa.setup.SuiteRun" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

The Method in test run before suite and display on report. But I don't want to display this test on report generated by testNG.

Is there any way to do this or any way to execute this method without mentioning in `testng.xml`?

Comment: So you want to invoke a method to prepare for the whole test suite? It is not a real test, just some setup steps? Would you please try `@BeforeSuite`? http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Comment: Yes I am using @@BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite and to run these method and test to run this in testng.xml file, but I want to hide the this test from generated report.